# apk not listed in app installer in phone

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

I have come up with a small camera application. It is working as expected in the Android emulator, but when I load the same in the SD card of an Android phone, the apk is not listed in the app installer of the phone. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are simply copying the APK file onto the SD card. That is not the same as installing an application. To install the application you need to open the APK file, so the operating system can properly install it.

There are many ways you can open an APK file on an Android device:

- Put the app in the Android Market (or other Market)
- Email the APK to the device
- Use a file manager app to open the APK from the SD card
- Open the APK from a network location, perhaps using Dropbox
- Open a web link on the phone pointing to the location of the APK (you may need to set the mime-type for APK files on the web server)